# Image embedded in Excel using POI but not showing

Tags: java, excel, tomcat7, apache-poi

I have created an excel file using POI and embedded image in it. its working fine. When i embed it in web application and deployed on apache tomcat server. Image is not showing up in excel file. Below is the code,

```
HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Sheet1");
InputStream logo_image = new FileInputStream("C:\\Logo.jpg");
byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(logo_image);
int picIndex = workbook.addPicture(bytes, Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG);
logo_image.close();

HSSFPatriarch drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();

ClientAnchor my_anchor = new HSSFClientAnchor();
my_anchor.setCol1(0);
my_anchor.setRow1(1);
HSSFPicture my_picture = drawing.createPicture(my_anchor, picIndex);
my_picture.resize(.4);

FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File( "C:\\image_example1.xls"));
workbook.write(out);
out.close();
```

Note: It is working on 1 tomcat instance but on another machine excel is being generated but image is not embedded.

I have tried adding `my_anchor.setCol12(2);my_anchor.setRow2(0);` as well, but no help.

Comment: Do you have graphics available? POI needs AWT to do some image and font sizing operations - see the [big warning in the POI docs](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Autofit)

Comment: graphics are available. Same code is running on one machine but not working on another.

Comment: Make sure you really are running headless / running from a graphics environment, and make sure it's the same JVM on both. If it works in one place, it's a setup issue, not a code issue!

Comment: I got the same problem. You were able to solve it?